# Per-User Defines In Xcode

Tags: xcode

My team is currently working a project.  We all have to connect to specific session of our software when debugging our work.  The original solution to this was to hard code the session ID into our login screens when working, but of course this meant having that stuff checked in and wiped out when doing SVN updates.

I thought setting up a User-Defined setting in Xcode would do the trick, but that turns out to be project wide as well.

Is there a way I could store this data in a per-user way, like in xcuserdata, and have it be easily editable as well?  I know something like an environment variable would do the trick, but if there's some way to do this via the Build Settings, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the session info into a new plist file (mySession.plist) in the project folder.  Add that plist file to the .gitignore.  Add the plist file to the build and have the app grab it from the bundle.

Comment: That might just do it.  I'll give it a whirl here and see how it works.  That way I can keep a reference in the project so it can be edited.

Comment: Yeah, this is a simplified version of what I do with my projects.  It works very well for me.

Comment: When you clone the project won't it complain about the missing plist file?

Comment: Well, each dev needs to have their own local plist file, so the file won't be missing.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use a compiler constant which can be unset when you want to test with a real session id?

To define:

[image]
To use:

```
NSString *sessionId;

#if USE_TEST_SESSION_ID

sessionId = TEST_SESSION_ID;

#else // !USE_TEST_SESSION_ID

sessionId = sessionIdTextEdit.stringValue;   // or whatever

#endif // USE_TEST_SESSION_ID
```

Comment: That still is shared across the project.  That gets checked in with every SVN update in the project.pbxproj file.